# Using StackView on different sized buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am having problems using stack view with different sized buttons.

This is what I am trying to achieve with StackView
[image]

I'm having issues with stack view because buttons '=' and '0' are different size.

This is what I've managed, but you can see the the alignment is not correct and the sizing is off.
[image]

> By looking at the images, does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve the desired look?

Comment: What about using `UICollectionView`, I think its much better. It will give you another benefit to support devices before iOS 9

Comment: @HossamGhareeb I've not tried ```UICollectionView```. Since i'm building a calculator to work on all iOS devices I thought the StackView would be suitable for my Universal StoryBoard. I'm having issues because of the '=' and '+' buttons. They are different size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution(for `=` button).
[image]

The Distributions of stack views is(from top to bottom in `Outline`):

#### Fill Proportionally

#### Fill

#### Fill Equally

#### Fill Equally

Answer (score 0):

try to set `Alignment` attributes to `Center` and `Distribution` to `Equal Spacing` for your `UIStackView` element, and set the view mode to `Center` for each `UIButton` elements at Attributes Inspector.